# Decorators for functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-generics, reduce, function-composition

I'm trying to make a statically type-checked "decorators" for functions. Basically, it is a helper for function composition from the right to remove the nesting.

The issue is that while types are inferred fine in one direction (from the input to the handler (the last argument)), they aren't inferred in the opposite direction. How to fix that?

```
// Should infer type Handler<InputContext, { a: string, b: boolean }>, but gets Handler<InputContext, unknown>
const myHandler2 = decorate(
  addToInput((_c: InputContext) => ({ y: 10 })),
  addToOutput(_r => ({ b: true })),
  async ({ x, y }): Promise<OutputContext> => {
    // Both x and y are inferred fine!

    return {
      a: `x = ${x + y}`
    };
  }
);
```

[TypeScript Playground with full code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=true&noErrorTruncation=true&pretty=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&ts=5.0.0-dev.20230208#code/C4TwDgpgBAshBOBzCAeAggGigIQHxQF4oB5AWwEth0sBrCEAewDMd8AyHAbgFgAoPgPQCoAYQYA7YBAAewKOQDOUAFYBXBXICG4qAwBGyiAGM5Ad0oALeeLCq5AE03BNfUJCgAJbfYA2CFACSWMT4RAAUfFBQRhJSsgBcUAF8AJSE%20AAK8AwUCqghPPy8QlAA6vCaYEqant5%208K7g0AAixgwVwO2BWAByQVA9xMGhUBG8UeIywIle4r7%20fb0hqem1c-XdJLiFfEyq4ibkElD2bR2oATZ2wXa2wLhjURZ1CDMv8IFXwDfAd7ipb3W-kudx%20f0KewOwCOOlOMXO1CSXzB1ygAC0HpEoKRTABGRKteFOLqYJGgki3VEYjBY55A%20CA%20YfEGo4iU%204AtZMxEYiH7Q7HOHtJyoUnYLAs74U36ogCaWAxj2xeIJZ2JHzFWHl6NwNPGyoATKqiZ0PuKyaz2VrdbT3oyNpKURzeCl7f5SbzdvzoYK1VJEeaRBLkdLyQANLUKzH6nH4qCE4WmgORnV6qI4o3xv1dQNYCNQWU2mOmADMxsTXSDFqlbJlUrDRaedq5DpDtb%20nNm3I92y9UJhJz9ECVADox3SmQpEgAxb0wgDaAF0VgBvLHwCDAVTwHQT%20oKEcb%20yqIwQABK5EQFmAYTCmiMRiwFjSBHw96MUAA-FALHeH2lEmfPgAF8%20D4chJAQJh72gSUxEg2QoDXfVpEScRVFIPQEEKUCiggqR4Gg09QzseC4jkZCok0RINHgCDEBwsDimEABlE9TwUBQ9h8HwQGsJgECULtWzuMipidMTZH%20XgYnEDRsRAYSEAABkIQcTWHLFNAUEADlGFcoGkKBgMSODYimV0oCyHJFHydlJPuVZKKiKANy3HckKxFyoGoqAAAMjKIAASFdpGAvyvOMwoolwlIdl4UhFPeZSwgM1CoAAVmMlIsRHYALAgcQwgYVZZIUBg-BHHwGEQMI-MSpT4GUxIGHZNSQoAKRY4gehHWj6PIJgQGKlJwpSHL9RHIwnCMX9oFfaIJHKyqEGyeA6oa5LEj8rAIHG%20KSmwbTyA-IUOnaLB7AYCAlHEBh8vovgyrkMBtI0CxslUK81M2EIwkshNzuZCVgmGdIsUmRCFtk8jVkhm8YYsg7WPYm6uNUHi%20IggT4CUNxoEaz5RPM2QJJJ51noUxrcTUs6RSVV7OPyz6r3%20tMfJ0vTUsM4zTK%20BzLOs3I7LrBzQnwZyojc7cdEllzfIC9rQvCyLgOi4zUnizb6Vxbn0qy4CJqiPKCqKkroaWiqICqmqNqSnWWra4KVy6nq%20uAOjxEQQbhoYUa-PG3LpuAWawnm-AyqtkdVvaO3qe23b9qYkoYHaaBNHsAA3bRT3sdSK1xqB8qcaI6WQasfLmAR2hIuR8YUJ6lq0ex7AAFQYSUfv6adhjCIjTRARIwkRhIkhffBpwB7NgdgBBkE2addRIMHXwhqZSvJuGpm5scpvJrBd-79phpH4A0kN%20LKYztuGHbOwu9BqBF77%208B6H0-EmIcen6nk0un6foQxZ5IHyFgRe4s15QwjpvBa8Nh7kxSCbQqw9Vg7zHI%20KAh9X7H2HufNI2lgHzyAYvOKydWIWFaj4PO2MEBFyaC2YE-N95IR8jRD29EsB6ESHoBgVttDGSXnoe%20yBgBCXeETUizD9g0DuqYcQ0lKbayZAaWmQ4lTX3bpKW8AB9IwfNiYITPqggyg8oC4lUobFI7MNG33ZGEbR8BjFQC4UXeAqhoCWOsZzD8essB8UNokIWtkUB32AGLJykVDr3SsEZbwUA%20KaA3PxVaEA85MAghAAAhExby0sPJyyottQKUAQpGQANTxJVvqGK6tYpa3tsovWiQDZG0wflZB5toFySjtVWq9UGn1EzK1OsStXa9X6l7H2I0xqtKmjNOaG9ukrXgGtOO7xMw7SgHtUhRQSgsQoRjah4gcZ0PcITMyhisAGV8hMxAnDuG8L8Pw4CgjhGbjEfSCRYSpHiBkQwORCim5U3eCWVRGl1Et00V8HRejqwCycaY8x2UrFYkZu9Fmv4UX6hsaE%20xjiFrcxcR7dxyKvG6R8WlPx2VAnZGFiE%20y5NxaeWqVAKJ%20UeZxISUkmhKzUlQHSZMbJRRcmbhlsy7yhT-LFNKVACpIAqneTVliOpTElH1BLE0zK2VcrtLNos5a1telrPpGWXQTsSku26uM9hkyhrTIDrM4Oodw6LSWdbGO61%20mNVNZs7ZhQgA)

Full code:

```
type Merge<A, B> = Omit<A, keyof B> & B;

// Context is just an object with input data
type Handler<I, O> = (
  context: I
) => Promise<O>;

// Wraps a Handler
type Decorator<I, NI, NO, O> = (
  next: Handler<NI, NO>
) => Handler<I, O>;

function decorate<Input, Output>(
  handler: Handler<Input, Output>
): Handler<Input, Output>;
function decorate<A, Input, Output, Z>(
  mw1: Decorator<A, Input, Output, Z>,
  handler: Handler<Input, Output>
): Handler<A, Z>;
function decorate<A, B, Input, Output, Y, Z>(
  mw1: Decorator<A, B, Y, Z>,
  mw2: Decorator<B, Input, Output, Y>,
  handler: Handler<Input, Output>
): Handler<A, Z>;
function decorate<A, B, C, Input, Output, X, Y, Z>(
  mw1: Decorator<A, B, Y, Z>,
  mw2: Decorator<B, C, X, Y>,
  mw3: Decorator<C, Input, Output, X>,
  handler: Handler<Input, Output>
): Handler<A, Z>;
function decorate(
  ...handlers: Function[]
) {
  return handlers.reduceRight((acc, h) => acc ? h(acc) : h)
}

interface InputContext {
  x: number;
}

interface OutputContext {
  a: string;
}

// Successfully infers Handler<InputContext, OutputContext>
const myHandler0 = decorate(
  async ({ x }: InputContext): Promise<OutputContext> => {
    return {
      a: `x = ${x}`
    };
  }
);

myHandler0({ x: 5 })
  .then(o => console.log(`myHandler0: output = ${JSON.stringify(o)}`))
  .catch(e => console.error(`myHandler0: `, e));

// Basic decorator, does nothing
const passthrough = <I, O>(): Decorator<I, I, O, O> =>
  next => context => next(context);

// Successfully infers type Handler<InputContext, OutputContext>
const myHandler1 = decorate(
  passthrough(),
  async ({ x }: InputContext): Promise<OutputContext> => {
    return {
      a: `x = ${x}`
    };
  }
);

myHandler1({ x: 5 })
  .then(o => console.log(`myHandler1: output = ${JSON.stringify(o)}`))
  .catch(e => console.error(`myHandler1: `, e));

// More advanced decorators that change Input and/or Output types
const addToInput = <I, F, O>(factory: (context: I) => F): Decorator<I, Merge<I, F>, O, O> =>
  next => context => next({ ...context, ...factory(context) });

const addToOutput = <I, O, F>(factory: (context: O) => F): Decorator<I, I, O, Merge<O, F>> =>
  next => context => next(context).then(c => ({ ...c, ...factory(c) }) as Merge<O, F>);

// Should infer type Handler<InputContext, { a: string, b: boolean }>, but gets Handler<InputContext, unknown>
const myHandler2 = decorate(
  addToInput((_c: InputContext) => ({ y: 10 })),
  addToOutput(_r => ({ b: true })),
  async ({ x, y }): Promise<OutputContext> => {
    // Both x and y are inferred fine!

    return {
      a: `x = ${x + y}`
    };
  }
);

myHandler2({ x: 5 })
  .then(o => console.log(`myHandler2: output = ${JSON.stringify(o)}`))
  .catch(e => console.error(`myHandler2: `, e));

// Should infer type Handler<InputContext, { a: string, b: boolean }>, but gets Handler<InputContext, unknown>
const myHandler3 = decorate(
  addToInput((_c: InputContext) => ({ y: 10 })),
  passthrough(),
  addToOutput(_r => ({ b: true })),
  async ({ x, y }): Promise<OutputContext> => {
    // Both x and y are inferred fine!

    return {
      a: `x = ${x + y}`
    };
  }
);

myHandler3({ x: 5 })
  .then(o => console.log(`myHandler3: output = ${JSON.stringify(o)}`))
  .catch(e => console.error(`myHandler3: `, e));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue is that while types are inferred fine in one direction (from the input to the handler (the last argument)), **they aren't inferred in the opposite direction**. How to fix that?

When working with TypeScript's advanced type system, I have found it useful to follow one rule: **don't try to be too clever**, otherwise you end up with really really difficult to understand code!

Having said that, I don't think there's a way to fix the problem you are facing because **type inference in TypeScript works in one direction (left-to-right).**

You may be able to find the truth of the matter in these two PRs both of which improve features around function composition:

1. [Variadic tuple types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094)
2. [Higher order function type inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215)

That second PR contains sentences like *"...in the **left-to-right processing** of the function call arguments..."* and *"...as the arguments are **processed left-to-right**..."* which are strong hint that inference is NOT bidirectional as your situation would like it to be.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you reached the limits of TypeScript type inference here.

You are passing type parameters through several functions that do not even use them, so they *should* leave the concrete assignment of those type parameters open. But it seems TypeScript cannot hand through the concrete type from right to left (as [Eric Mutta mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75442914/1883995), TypeScript infers types left-to-right).

```
const addToInput = <I, F, O>(factory: (context: I) => F): Decorator<I, Merge<I, F>, O, O> =>
  next => context => next({ ...context, ...factory(context) });

const myHandler2 = decorate(
  addToInput((_c: InputContext) => ({ y: 10 })),
  addToOutput(_r => ({ b: true })),
  async ({ x, y }): Promise<OutputContext> => {
    // Both x and y are inferred fine!

    return {
      a: `x = ${x + y}`
    };
  }
);
```

To fix the type inference problem in the `myHandler2` example, you need to give TypeScript a hint about the unused `O` type parameter. Unfortunately, when a function has *n* type parameters, TypeScript does not allow to specify just one. Type parameters with default also do not help, because as soon as one parameter is given, the defaults are taken as-is and type inference is disabled. This means you would have to specify all three parameters, resulting in a lot of type annotations.

A workaround that came to mind is to "curry" the `addToInput()` function into a function without arguments that takes the `O` type parameter and returns the previous `addToInput()` function, which now only needs the remaining two type parameters.

```
const addToInput = <O,>() => <I, F>(factory: (context: I) => F): Decorator<I, Merge<I, F>, O, O> =>
    next => context => next({ ...context, ...factory(context) });
```

(The wonky `<O,>` is only needed if you have JSX enabled.)

The outer function can then be called with an explicit type for `O`, while for the inner function, we let TypeScript apply type inference:

```
const myHandler2 = decorate(
  // explicitly declare OutputContext early:
  addToInput<Merge<OutputContext, { b: boolean }>>()((_c: InputContext) => ({ y: 10 })),
  addToOutput(_r => ({ b: true })),
  async ({ x, y }): Promise<OutputContext> => {
    // Both x and y are inferred fine!

    return {
      a: `x = ${x + y}`
    };
  }
);
```

Now, with only one explicit type annotation, `myHandler`'s type is inferred to be `Handler<InputContext, Merge<OutputContext, { b: boolean }>>`, which can be simplified to the desired result `Handler<InputContext, { a: string, b: boolean }>>`.

It is a bit regrettable that the workaround actually has impact on the JavaScript/runtime code, but I found no way to mitigate the problem with only type annotations.

[TypeScript Playground with adapted full example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=true&noErrorTruncation=true&pretty=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&ts=5.0.0-dev.20230208#code/C4TwDgpgBAshBOBzCAeAggGigIQHxQF4oB5AWwEth0sBrCEAewDMd8AyHAbgFgAoPgPQCoAYQYA7YBAAewKOQDOUAFYBXBXICG4qAwBGyiAGM5Ad0oALeeLCq5AE03BNfUJCgAJbfYA2CFACSWMT4RAAUfFBQRhJSsgBcUAF8AJSE+AAK8AwUCqghPPy8QlAA6vCaYEqant5+8K7g0AAixgwVwO2BWAByQVA9xMGhUBG8UeIywIle4r7+fb0hqem1c-XdJLiFfEyq4ibkElD2bR2oATZ2wXa2wLhjURZ1CDMv8IFXwDfAd7ipb3W-kudx+f0KewOwCOOlOMXO1CSXzB1ygAC0HpEoKRTABGRKteFOLqYJGgki3VEYjBY55A+CA+YfEGo4iU+4AtZMxEYiH7Q7HOHtJyoUnYLAs74U36ogCaWAxj2xeIJZ2JHzFWHl6NwNPGyoATKqiZ0PuKyaz2VrdbT3oyNpKURzeCl7f5SbzdvzoYK1VJEeaRBLkdLyQANLUKzH6nH4qCE4WmgORnV6qI4o3xv1dQNYCNQWU2mOmADMxsTXSDFqlbJlUrDRaedq5DpDtb+nNm3I92y9UJhJz9ECVADox3SmQpEgAxb0wgDaAF0VgBvLHwCDAVTwHQT+oKEcb+yqIwQABK5EQFmAYTCmiMRiwFjSBHw96MUAA-FALHeH2lEmfPgAF8+D4chJAQJh72gSUxEg2QoDXfVpEScRVFIPQEEKUCiggqR4Gg09QzseC4jkZCok0RINHgCDEBwsDimEABlE9TwUBQ9h8HwQGsJgECULtWzuMipidMTZH+XgYnEDRsRAYSEAABkIQcTWHLFNAUEADlGFcoGkKBgMSODYimV0oCyHJFHydlJPuVZKKiKANy3HckKxFyoGoqAAAMjKIAASFdpGAvyvOMwoolwlIdl4UhFPeZSwgM1CoAAVmMlIsRHYALAgcQwgYVZZIUBg-BHHwGEQMI-MSpT4GUxIGHZNSQoAKRY4gehHWj6PIJgQGKlJwpSHL9RHIwnCMX9oFfaIJHKyqEGyeA6oa5LEj8rAIHG+KSmwbTyA-IUOnaLB7AYCAlHEBh8vovgyrkMBtI0CxslUK81M2EIwkshNzuZCVgmGdIsUmRCFtk8jVkhm8YYsg7WPYm6uNUHi+IggT4CUNxoEaz5RPM2QJJJ51noUxrcTUs6RSVV7OPyz6r3+tMfJ0vTUsM4zTK+BzLOs3I7LrBzQnwZyojc7cdEllzfIC9rQvCyLgOi4zUnizb6Vxbn0qy4CJqiPKCqKkroaWiqICqmqNqSnWWra4KVy6nq+uAOjxEQQbhoYUa-PG3LpuAWawnm-AyqtkdVvaO3qe23b9qYkoYHaaBNHsAA3bRT3sdSK1xqB8qcaI6WQasfLmAR2hIuR8YUQRhFKU2oAAIiMbd4BAejW58+x7AAFQYSUAHIlGIIumigV6KlITcECwShom0KAsKgPI5Agvvs4OCB4iepatH7ofJR+oYHhffBNmnB4iNNEBEjCRGEiSS+oGnAHs2B2AEGQa-dRIGDV8EMpilXJnDKY3MxxTXJlgaBd92jDWfsANIht4qUwzoPBg7Y7A-X6EMd+t97z30fsgxIxA34f3LEDTY+CsBwCQPkLAN9xYgKhhHcBC14ZP3JikE2hUn6rCgWOR8UB4HEMQU-VBaRtI-0YSgAhN84rJ2ED0Bgph+KCSpu8A0Y9J7uE6C2YE-NYFyL-jg4ADksAGT0IkPQDArYr2ArgaSlNtZMgNLTIcSpMEny+CgBh5j7KmJsXYhxfgnEuP+reAA+kYPmxMEIoKEQZB+UBcSqUNikdmvjsHsjCDE+AKTV6JA9qoaAWScmcw-HrLAfFDaJCFrZBRwSkni08vqKIh17pWCMt4KAfFNAbk0fAI8UAmAQQgAAQiYt5aWHk5ZUW2oFKAIUjIAGoBkq06VFLEsUtb2w8XrRIBsjZiPygI82HC5JR2qrVeqhz6iZlanWJWrter9S9j7EaY0zlTRmnNMBNyVqjNjg8xqmYdpQD2soooJQWIWFaj4PO2MED6IJu8ImpEQk+Roh7eiWBbGr3CRASJhLcHIGAEJTFZkklYH2DQO6phxCuMPto+kJYvEaR8cfYe-iLFi2iQU+J1YBbFLSRk7K2SsSM3eizX80r9S5IsbEhktcxULW5kSspFTxpVN0jUtKdTsqNOyMLFpotybtLlt0-KPN+mDOGai0ZEA84TMmDMooczNwyw6d5JZ-kVlrKgJskA2zvJqz2ZrJi7j6glmOZlbKuULlmyBcta2dy47vDLLoJ2qyXbdQ+fir5Q0fkBz+cHUO4dFrAutjHda4Ls0J2hUnXgQA)

While type inference is a nice thing to avoid a lot of boilerplate type annotations, I would recommend to keep using type annotations when it helps the type checker or the developer (or both). For example, explicitly declaring the type of a local variable helps the TypeScript Language Service and through it your IDE to generate meaningful suggestions when constructing the expression, and it may also help your future me when reading the code (maybe without extensive IDE support, e.g. on GitHub). TypeScript of course still checks that the expression type it derives is assignable to your explicitly given type.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that I can explicitly set types. But it would get very inconvenient when you will use this code on an actual project. Imagine a web request handler: raw request => parse => coerce types like dates => validate schema => add session data => etc. Types will get complicated. Also, in you example the output type is wrong: `explicitly declare OutputContext early:`. Should be `addToInput<Merge<OutputContext, { b: true }>>` instead :)

Comment: Well, in your case, like other explained, too, there is no way around specifying _some_ types explicitly. I just provided a "trick" to _reduce_ the number of types you need to specify explicitly. And yeah, "Types will get complicated"... if things _are_ complicated.
Thanks for pointing out the incorrect type, I'll fix this in my answer. However, your suggestion is also incorrect. Try it in my Playground link: It must be `{ b: boolean }`, not `{ b: true }`, otherwise there is a type error in the next line (or you'd need to add `as const` in the next line).